# Java- Juntar 2 vectores para crear una matriz

Tags: java, array

Tengo un ejercicio en el que a partir de dos vectores cree una matriz en el que vector1[i]*Vector2[j] sea igual a nuestra matriz[i][j] ( en este caso me piden que el vector 1 sea de 50 y el vector2 sea de 20, la matriz seria [50][20]

Tengo que realizar algo como esto: ( en el que se vean los vectores 1 y 2 en horizontal y vertical de mi matriz y en su interior se vayan multiplicando las posiciones).

```
---------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,
4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80,
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,
6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60,66,72,78,84,90,96,102,108,114,120,
7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105,112,119,126,133,140,
8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80,88,96,104,112,120,128,136,144,152,160,
9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99,108,117,126,135,144,153,162,171,180,
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,
11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,110,121,132,143,154,165,176,187,198,209,220,
12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120,132,144,156,168,180,192,204,216,228,240,
13,26,39,52,65,78,91,104,117,130,143,156,169,182,195,208,221,234,247,260,
14,28,42,56,70,84,98,112,126,140,154,168,182,196,210,224,238,252,266,280,
15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240,255,270,285,300,
16,32,48,64,80,96,112,128,144,160,176,192,208,224,240,256,272,288,304,320,
17,34,51,68,85,102,119,136,153,170,187,204,221,238,255,272,289,306,323,340,
18,36,54,72,90,108,126,144,162,180,198,216,234,252,270,288,306,324,342,360,
19,38,57,76,95,114,133,152,171,190,209,228,247,266,285,304,323,342,361,380,
20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,
21,42,63,84,105,126,147,168,189,210,231,252,273,294,315,336,357,378,399,420,
22,44,66,88,110,132,154,176,198,220,242,264,286,308,330,352,374,396,418,440,
23,46,69,92,115,138,161,184,207,230,253,276,299,322,345,368,391,414,437,460,
24,48,72,96,120,144,168,192,216,240,264,288,312,336,360,384,408,432,456,480,
25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,
26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,234,260,286,312,338,364,390,416,442,468,494,520,
27,54,81,108,135,162,189,216,243,270,297,324,351,378,405,432,459,486,513,540,
28,56,84,112,140,168,196,224,252,280,308,336,364,392,420,448,476,504,532,560,
29,58,87,116,145,174,203,232,261,290,319,348,377,406,435,464,493,522,551,580,
30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390,420,450,480,510,540,570,600,
31,62,93,124,155,186,217,248,279,310,341,372,403,434,465,496,527,558,589,620,
32,64,96,128,160,192,224,256,288,320,352,384,416,448,480,512,544,576,608,640,
33,66,99,132,165,198,231,264,297,330,363,396,429,462,495,528,561,594,627,660,
34,68,102,136,170,204,238,272,306,340,374,408,442,476,510,544,578,612,646,680,
35,70,105,140,175,210,245,280,315,350,385,420,455,490,525,560,595,630,665,700,
36,72,108,144,180,216,252,288,324,360,396,432,468,504,540,576,612,648,684,720,
37,74,111,148,185,222,259,296,333,370,407,444,481,518,555,592,629,666,703,740,
38,76,114,152,190,228,266,304,342,380,418,456,494,532,570,608,646,684,722,760,
39,78,117,156,195,234,273,312,351,390,429,468,507,546,585,624,663,702,741,780,
40,80,120,160,200,240,280,320,360,400,440,480,520,560,600,640,680,720,760,800,
41,82,123,164,205,246,287,328,369,410,451,492,533,574,615,656,697,738,779,820,
42,84,126,168,210,252,294,336,378,420,462,504,546,588,630,672,714,756,798,840,
43,86,129,172,215,258,301,344,387,430,473,516,559,602,645,688,731,774,817,860,
44,88,132,176,220,264,308,352,396,440,484,528,572,616,660,704,748,792,836,880,
45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360,405,450,495,540,585,630,675,720,765,810,855,900,
46,92,138,184,230,276,322,368,414,460,506,552,598,644,690,736,782,828,874,920,
47,94,141,188,235,282,329,376,423,470,517,564,611,658,705,752,799,846,893,940,
48,96,144,192,240,288,336,384,432,480,528,576,624,672,720,768,816,864,912,960,
49,98,147,196,245,294,343,392,441,490,539,588,637,686,735,784,833,882,931,980,
50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950,1000,
---------------
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int v []= new int [50];
    int p []= new int [20];
    int m[][]=new int[50][20];


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        v[i] = (i + 1);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        p[i] = (i + 1);
    }

    juntarVectores(v,p,m);
    Matriz(v,p,m);

}

 public static void Matriz(int []v,int []p,int[][]m) {

        System.out.println("Esta es tu matriz juntando ambos vectores:");
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static int[][] juntarVectores(int []v,int[]p,int[][]m) {

        int[][] myJoinedArray = new int[v.length][p.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myJoinedArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myJoinedArray[i].length; j++) {
                myJoinedArray[i][j] = v[i] * p[j];
            }
        }

        m = myJoinedArray;
        return m;

    }
```

pero a mi por consola me sale lo siguiente:

```
Esta es tu matriz juntando ambos vectores:
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Que estoy realizando mal? alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: ¿Si te funcionó mi solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltó reasignar el valor de **m**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int v[] = new int[50];
    int p[] = new int[20];
    int m[][] = new int[50][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        v[i] = (i + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        p[i] = (i + 1);
    }        

    m = juntarVectores(v, p, m); // <--- AQUI
    Matriz(v, p, m);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias justo era eso lo que no sabía cómo colocar :)

Answer (score 1):

Voy a explicarte el error con un ejemplo. Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente
código con una función que calcula el doble de un numero:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10;

    calcularDoble(a);

    System.out.println(a);
}

public static void calcularDoble(int a) {
    int b = a * 2;

    a = b;
}
```

Esperamos que luego de ejecutar `calcularDoble`, `a` sea 20, pero con lo que
nos encontramos es que `a` sigue siendo `10`. Esto pasa porque dentro de la
función `calcularDoble`, `a` es otra variable y no la que tenemos en `main`,
por eso al intentar asignarle algo solo la cambia dentro de
`calcularDoble`. Si queremos que cambia el `a` dentro de `main` tenemos que
devolver el resultado en `calcularDoble` y asignarlo dentro de `main`
de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10;

    a = calcularDoble(a);

    System.out.println(a);
}

public static int calcularDoble(int a) {
    int b = a * 2;
    return b;
}
```

En tu caso haces lo mismo pero con `juntarVectores`. Al hacer:

```
m = myJoinedArray;
```

Estas cambiando la variable `m` dentro de `juntarVectores` y no en `main`,
por eso te muestra la matriz con ceros (el valor por defecto).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por explicarme mi error, gracias a ti he podido comprender el fallo correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ya te dieron una solución y también te explicaron la razón del porqué tu programa no funcionaba correctamente; sin embargo, te daré otra solución.

Si te das cuenta, todo este código está bien:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int v []= new int [50];
    int p []= new int [20];
    int m[][]=new int[50][20];


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        v[i] = (i + 1);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        p[i] = (i + 1);
    }

    juntarVectores(v,p,m);
    Matriz(v,p,m);

}
```

Pero la parte más interesante es esta línea:

```
juntarVectores(v,p,m);
```

La variable `m` hace referencia a un objeto de tipo `int[][]`, esto quiere decir que cuando llamas al método `juntarVectores`, en realidad estarás pasando implícitamente la dirección base (es decir, del primer elemento) del objeto que tenga almacenada la variable `m` (debemos recordar que la variable `m` es un [puntero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)) implícito, aunque en Java no haya soporte para [punteros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)), siempre existen internamente).

Entonces, entendiendo este concepto básico, podríamos decir que si le pasamos la referencia que tiene guardada `m` (la variable del `main`) al parámetro `m` (del método `juntarVectores`), el método podría modificar el contenido de la matriz que se haya pasado por referencia de forma implícita (digo `implícito` porqué en Java no se puede pasar directamente la dirección de memoria de una variable; sin embargo, el compilador se encarga de pasar la dirección que tenga almacenada el puntero `m`).

Es decir, el método `juntarVectores` quedaría de esta forma:

```
public static void juntarVectores(int []v, int[]p, int[][]m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) 
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++)
                m[i][j] = v[i] * p[j];
    }
}
```